# SQL query to receive an attribute value which has single/double quotes

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I need to run a SQL query(SQLite Database) in my android application. Query is as follows.

```
public Cursor getLongitudeLatitude(String port)
{
    Cursor cur = null;  
    String qry = "SELECT latitude, longitude FROM port WHERE name='"+port+"'";
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();         
    cur = db.rawQuery(qry,new String [] {});    
    return cur; 
}
```

The original values that should return from this query contains single and double Quotes. for ex: 36°7'59''N

But it actually retuns 36°7. How can I query to get the entire value.

Thank you

Comment: How do you know that it contans single and double Quotes? Did you get the sqlite file and browsed it?

Comment: in addition to Sherif comment ... you did wrong insert ... try to use db.insert instead of db.rawQuery or use rawQuery with params

Comment: Where did you get this database from?

Comment: Oh.. I checked. The value in the SQLite is 36°7. That's why. I inserted data to the sqlite DB by reading an XML file. Seems like mistakenly added half of the record... Thank you very much Sherif, Selvin and Ariel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is not at calling the value, I think you had an error when writing it to the database. You should check if it's correctly in your DB (use Firefox SQL manager or something).

How did you write it to your DB?

Comment: Ya it is my fault. I have mistakenly inserted wrong data. I inserted data by reading an xml file..Thank you.